# Visio - Reverse Engineering a Database Model from an Azure SQL Server DB -- Crashing

Tags: sql-server, azure, reverse-engineering, visio

In the Microsoft SQL Server Setup for database drivers, I have checked off SQL Server, SQL Server Native Client 10.0, and SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

I have created 6 data sources, one for each "type of data source" (user data source or system data source, as file data source doesn't show up) multiplied by each driver (SQL Server, Native Client 10.0, and Native Client 11.0).

When creating the data sources, I request SQL Server authentication and give the username and password.

Before saving, I test the connection and it succeeds.

When I try to connect to the database, it requests my username/password. When I give my credentials, Visio crashes. If I misspell my credentials, Visio tells me that my credentials were invalid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are significant differences between SQL Azure and SQL Server.  I remember some versions of Visual Studio and SSMS would crash with certain operations against SQL Azure because of those differences, until Microsoft released an updated version specifically to handle SQL Azure.  You may have to download the database to an on-prem SQL Server and reverse engineer it there. See also: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/83ccc5a0-1fcd-43fd-87bf-a3e02fbda94a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me: I used the ODBC generic driver with the Native Client 11.0.

One could also try the suggestion in the comment above by @mellamokb.